# What is the difference between init() and window.init()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-cloud-endpoints

I have read through the following recipe, which shows a way to power an AngularJS frontend with a Google Cloud Endpoints backend:

https://cloud.google.com/resources/articles/angularjs-cloud-endpoints-recipe-for-building-modern-web-applications

What I don't understand is the appendix on the AngularJS and Cloud Endpoints initialization. The relevant section is the following:

> Appendix: Tips on AngularJS + Cloud Endpoints Initialization Tip #1:
>   Be careful on the initialization sequence
>
> The guestbook app loads three different JS libraries in the following
>   sequence:
>
> - AngularJS
> - The guestbook app
> - Google API Client, which contains the Endpoints functionalities
>
> To follow this sequence, the index.html contains the following
>   `<script>` tags in the `<head>` tag for loading each of the JS libraries:
>
> ```
> <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>  
> <script src="js/guestbook.js"></script>  
> <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
> ```
>
> Once loaded, the third library (Google API Client) calls the
>   initialization function specified by its ‘onload’ parameter. In this
>   case, the init() function is expected and invoked. Tip #2: Enter into
>   the AngularJS world as quickly as possible
>
> In the initialization sequence, we use the two functions:
>
> ```
> init() function
> window.init() function
> ```
>
> This init() function is defined in guestbook.js in the following way:
>
> ```
> function init() {   window.init(); }
> ```
>
> As you can see the code above, the function just calls window.init()
>   function (i.e. init() function defined in the global window object)
>   and does nothing else. The window.init() is defined in the AngularJS
>   controller as follows:
>
> ```
> $window.init= function() {   
>    $scope.$apply($scope.load_guestbook_lib);
> };
> ```
>
> In AngularJS, the global window object is accessed by “$window”
>   notation which is a wrapper for it. It is a best practice in AngularJS
>   not to access the window object directly to improve testability.
>
> The reason why you would not want to execute the initialization in the
>   first init() method is so you can put as much of the code as possible
>   in the AngularJS world, such as controllers, services and directives.
>   As a result, you can harness the full power of AngularJS and have all
>   your unit tests, integrations tests,and so forth.

It seems that a global function `init()` is being defined in an external javascript file. This `init()` function just calls `window.init()` (and is supposed to be called by the Google client library after it has loaded). But isn't window.init() nothing but the globally defined `init()` function? So wouldn't we get a loop here until `window.init()` (and thus `init()`) is being redefined?

Comment: Please don't rely on off-site resources. Show the code you're talking about. Off-site resources rot, and people shouldn't have to visit them to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This example tries to take the google api init event and transfer it to AngularJS scope.

When

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
```

is loaded it calls the init function defined globally, which in turn calls the init method defined on the window object. 
Since this function has access to the angular scopes, it plays well with angular

It makes it easier to wrap cloud endpoint calls in promises

Here is how to make it much easier
http://anandsekar.github.io/initialize-google-appengine-and-angularjs/

Comment: The init function defined globally is the init method defined on the window object. So I don't see why the code would not loop.

Answer (score 0):

guestbook.js defines an init function that appears from your description to be global. That init function is passed to the google client.js. That global init function just calls (another) global function at window.init. The angular module loaded first should have setup window.init via the angular provided $window. There is not a loop, client.js calls guestbook.js's init which calls the angular method $window.init, which is the same as window.init.

Comment: I don't quite understand: A globally defined function shows up as a property on the global object, that is window. So how can there be two different functions init and window.init? (So with my understanding, either guestbook.js overwrites the Angular-defined version or vice versa.)